# Portal for ArcGIS : Can't login due to url wrong port after nginx reverse proxy

Tags: arcgis, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm building an NginX reverse proxy (Ubuntu Server 22.04.1 - NginX 1.22.1) to open an internal Portal for ArcGIS to extranet.

The reverse proxy listen to 8054 and redirects to 2 internal servers using usual TLS 443 port

Everything works fine except a redirection occurring during Portal's login auth.

In Chrome's console, the info of faulty are :

```
        Request URL: https://myserver.mydomain/portal/sharing/rest/portals/self/subscriptionInfo?f=json&token=ARYpO8uD2SRx5tjuhTElBoDT_ojo9YRwvsX7XI51s3GIfvhlMIGpOjRXKN0g8fXFHgfenkIdg-YtF9TtyWvOomu9TyUm2x8mY4SfTlWSX41E9lyP_I0NVWO-xdwGzJqWDU8GJ4oi5sg53mvRH2OMdUA1bwN0fE-jcSEmK4EsxxOHBe6HZbciuGUCh4s8rgDbz7fBlpIdrFBryxe-YbvooLvb1Q8BsVSZFZFYBlclLQk.&callback=dojo_request_script_callbacks.dojo_request_script0
        Request Method: GET
        Status Code: 404 
        Remote Address: 10.0.128.36:443
        Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
        content-encoding: gzip
        content-type: text/html
        date: Wed, 25 Jan 2023 09:59:31 GMT
        server: nginx
        vary: Accept-Encoding
        :authority: myserver.mydomain
        :method: GET
        :path: /portal/sharing/rest/portals/self/subscriptionInfo?f=json&token=ARYpO8uD2SRx5tjuhTElBoDT_ojo9YRwvsX7XI51s3GIfvhlMIGpOjRXKN0g8fXFHgfenkIdg-YtF9TtyWvOomu9TyUm2x8mY4SfTlWSX41E9lyP_I0NVWO-xdwGzJqWDU8GJ4oi5sg53mvRH2OMdUA1bwN0fE-jcSEmK4EsxxOHBe6HZbciuGUCh4s8rgDbz7fBlpIdrFBryxe-YbvooLvb1Q8BsVSZFZFYBlclLQk.&callback=dojo_request_script_callbacks.dojo_request_script0
        :scheme: https
        accept: */*
        accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
        accept-language: fr-FR,fr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,nl;q=0.6
        dnt: 1
        sec-ch-ua: "Not_A Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="109", "Chromium";v="109"
        sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
        sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
        sec-fetch-dest: script
        sec-fetch-mode: no-cors
        sec-fetch-site: cross-site
        user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
```

Usual processed URL returns :

```
        Request URL: https://myserver.mydomain:8054/portal/sharing/rest/oauth2/authorize?client_id=arcgisonline&display=default&response_type=token&state=%7B%22portalUrl%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fmyserver.mydomain%3A8054%2Fportal%22%2C%22useLandingPage%22%3Atrue%7D&expiration=20160&locale=fr-fr&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fmyserver.mydomain%3A8054%2Fportal%2Fhome%2Faccountswitcher-callback.html&force_login=true&hideCancel=true&showSignupOption=true&canHandleCrossOrgSignIn=true&signuptype=esri
        Request Method: GET
        Status Code: 200 
        Remote Address: 10.0.128.36:8054
        Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
        access-control-allow-headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept
        access-control-allow-methods: GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS
        access-control-allow-origin: *
        access-control-max-age: 1200
        cache-control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
        content-encoding: gzip
        content-length: 1416
        content-type: text/html;charset=utf-8
        date: Wed, 25 Jan 2023 10:51:05 GMT
        expires: -1
        pragma: no-cache
        server: nginx/1.22.1
        vary: Origin,Accept-Encoding
        x-content-type-options: nosniff
        x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
        x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
        :authority: myserver.mydomain:8054
        :method: GET
        :path: /portal/sharing/rest/oauth2/authorize?client_id=arcgisonline&display=default&response_type=token&state=%7B%22portalUrl%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fmyserver.mydomain%3A8054%2Fportal%22%2C%22useLandingPage%22%3Atrue%7D&expiration=20160&locale=fr-fr&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fmyserver.mydomain%3A8054%2Fportal%2Fhome%2Faccountswitcher-callback.html&force_login=true&hideCancel=true&showSignupOption=true&canHandleCrossOrgSignIn=true&signuptype=esri
        :scheme: https
        accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
        accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
        accept-language: fr-FR,fr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,nl;q=0.6
        cache-control: max-age=0
        dnt: 1
        referer: https://myserver.mydomain:8054/portal/home/signin.html?useLandingPage=true
        sec-ch-ua: "Not_A Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="109", "Chromium";v="109"
        sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
        sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
        sec-fetch-dest: document
        sec-fetch-mode: navigate
        sec-fetch-site: same-origin
        sec-fetch-user: ?1
        upgrade-insecure-requests: 1
        user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
```

How can I catch, pass, redirect, return, or whatever, the url missing the port 8054 in order to continue auth processing ?

Here are the nginx general and server configs if it may help
Thanks for any help !

**nginx.conf**

```
<pre>
user    www-data    nginx;
worker_processes    auto;
error_log   /var/log/nginx/main_error.log;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

worker_rlimit_core  4096;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
    multi_accept on;
}

http {
    include /etc/nginx/phpconf/php_processes.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/mimetypes/mime.types;
    
    client_body_buffer_size 16K;
    client_header_buffer_size 1k;   
    client_max_body_size 12m;
    large_client_header_buffers 4 8k;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
    
    access_log  off;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/main_access.log;

    client_body_timeout 30;
    client_header_timeout 10;
    keepalive_timeout 75s;
    send_timeout 60;
    keepalive_requests 1000;

    proxy_cache_path    /var/nginx/cache1 levels=1:2 keys_zone=cache1:10m inactive=5m max_size=1G use_temp_path=off;    # (20230113)
    proxy_cache_path    /var/nginx/cache2 levels=1:2 keys_zone=cache2:10m inactive=5m max_size=1G use_temp_path=off;    # (20230113)

    # copies data between one FD and other from within the kernel
    # faster than read() + write()
    sendfile    on;

    # Limit whole filesize sending at once
    sendfile_max_chunk  512k;   #(20220905)

    # send headers in one piece, it is better than sending them one by one
    tcp_nopush  on;
    tcp_nodelay on;

    server_names_hash_bucket_size  64;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    default_type    application/octet-stream;

    gzip    on; 
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_min_length 256;    #(20220605 previous 50)
    gzip_proxied    any;
    gzip_vary   on; #(20220605 previous disabled)
    gzip_disable    “MSIE [1–6]\.(?!.*SV1)”; #(20220605 previous disabled)
    gzip_types
            application/atom+xml
            application/javascript
            application/json
            application/ld+json
            application/manifest+json
            application/rss+xml
            application/vnd.geo+json
            application/vnd.ms-fontobject
            application/x-font-ttf
            application/x-javascrip # (20200219)
            application/x-web-app-manifest+json
            application/xhtml+xml
            application/xml
            font/opentype
            image/bmp
            image/svg+xml
            image/png
            image/jpeg
            image/x-icon
            text/cache-manifest
            text/css
            text/javascript # (20200219)
            text/plain
            text/vcard
            text/vnd.rim.location.xloc
            text/vtt
            text/x-component
            text/x-cross-domain-policy;
            
    gzip_buffers 16 8k; #(2020110 previous 4k 8k)
    
    # allow the server to close connection on non responding client, this will free up memory
    reset_timedout_connection   on;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    # include /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/port8054.conf;
}

</pre>
```

**port8054.conf**

```
<pre>
server {
    ## Config base : 18/01/2023

        listen 8054 ssl http2;
        listen [::]:8054    ssl http2;

        ## Set TLS 1.2 (ArcGIS compliance)
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/tls/intra/cacert.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/tls/intra/cakey-stripped.key;
        ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/nginx/tls/intra/rootcacert.pem;

        ssl_protocols   TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1 TLSv1;
        ssl_ciphers     "ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384";  # previous : HIGH:!MD5:!ADH:!DH:!RC4:!RSA:!aNULL
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers      on;

        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
        ssl_session_timeout     10m;
        ssl_buffer_size 1400;

    ## Set on after debug
        ssl_stapling off;
        ssl_stapling_verify off;

        server_name  myserver.mydomain:8054;

        keepalive_timeout       75s;
        keepalive_requests      1000;

        # access_log    /var/log/nginx/port8054-access.log;

        ## Record errors
        error_log /var/log/nginx/port8054-error.log debug;

    proxy_http_version 1.1;

    ## Overwrite proxy response headers
    proxy_hide_header access-control-allow-methods;
    proxy_hide_header access-control-allow-headers;
    proxy_hide_header access-control-allow-origin;

    add_header access-control-allow-methods "GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS";
    add_header access-control-allow-headers "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept";
    add_header access-control-allow-origin "*";

    proxy_hide_header x-aspnet-version;
    proxy_hide_header x-powered-by;

    proxy_set_header    "Connection"    "";
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Host    $host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

    location ^~ /favicon.ico {
        
    }
    ## PHP files processing
    location ~ ^(.+\.php)(.*)$ {
        include        /etc/nginx/phpconf/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
        fastcgi_pass    unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index   index.php;
        fastcgi_buffers         8 16k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size     32k;
        fastcgi_hide_header             X-Powered-By;
        fastcgi_hide_header             X-CF-Powered-By;

        ## If error 404
        try_files $fastcgi_script_name =404;        
        }
    
    ## Set cache for following contents (20201106)
    location ~* \.(?:png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico|svg|otf|ttf|woff|woff2|doc|pdf|css)$ {
        include /etc/nginx/proxyparams/proxy_params;
        proxy_cache cache1;
        proxy_set_header    Host    $host;
        # proxy_pass https://otherserver.mydomain/$1;
        # proxy_ssl_verify off;
        # add_header X-Cache-Status $upstream_cache_status;
        # add_header Pragma "public";
        # add_header Cache-Control "max-age=86400, public";
    }
        
    location ^~ /portal/ {
                proxy_pass https://otherserver.mydomain/portal/;
        }
    
    location /10.9.1/{
            proxy_pass https://otherserver.mydomain/portal/home/10.9.1/;
        }

    location /sharing/rest/ {
        proxy_intercept_errors on;
        proxy_pass https://otherserver.mydomain/portal/sharing/rest/;
    }

    location ^~ /oauth2/ {
        proxy_pass https://otherserver.mydomain/portal/sharing/rest/oauth2/;
    }

    location /self/ {               
        proxy_pass https://otherserver.mydomain/portal/sharing/rest/portals/self/;
    }

    location ^~ /nodejs/ {
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        include /etc/nginx/proxyparams/proxy_params;
        proxy_pass https://thirdserver.mydomain/;           
        
        proxy_buffering on;
        proxy_buffer_size 16k;
        proxy_busy_buffers_size 24k;
        proxy_buffers 64 4k;
    
        client_max_body_size 12m;
    }   
}
</pre>
```

Comment: did you ever solve this, we're running into the same issue.

Comment: Unfortunately not, the workaround so far is to go through the usual TLS port 443. When a custom port is used, internal redirects in ArcGIS Enterprise cause a lot of mess. It seems that the installation must take into account the custom port number in order to ensure proper redirects. Even rewrites don't always respond correctly ...